# Any way to prevent this 'pinching?' with the cylinder?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I want to create a looping animation with moving red blood cells along with letters of the different blood types, I used and modified a cylinder in edit mode and this is the result, however there is a 'pinching' that is bothering me in the middle. (See Below)

I know this had something to do with the edges but is there any way to make these vanish?

Thank you for any help!

[image] [image]

Comment: It's getting subdivided into a 24-pole of triangles, which is bad topo for subdivision.  Delete the face and use a grid fill operation on the border that leaves to try for good, all quad, 3 and 5-pole topology.  Doing some searches for "3d topology" would probably help with learning about it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your answer so delete only the faces (but that gets rid of the edges, or only delete the middle face?) and then use grid fill to fill the edges all in?

Comment: Replace the center circle face with gridfill

Answer (score 10):

To add to Arafium's solution:

This topology will cause pinching because Blender tries to smooth between the second circle and the inner ngon circle:

[image]

But if you inset in order to create a co-planar circle the pinching will disappear as there is no need to smooth between the 2 circles:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Delete the circular face, select the edge loop like this[image]

Then press ctrl + f and select grid fill and done, this is the result
[image]